# Generators of a certain ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

[Crossposted](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87429/generators-of-a-certain-ideal) on MathOverflow.

The MathOverflow version of the question has been rewritten. For the sake of completeness, I pasted it here in a condensed form. I also deleted the old version.

Let $K$ be a commutative ring, and let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be indeterminates. Here $n$ is an integer $\ge3$. For $1\le i < j\le n$ put 
$$
x_{ij}:=\frac{1}{X_i-X_j}
$$
and let $Y_{ij}$ be an indeterminate. Let $I$ be the kernel of the $K$-algebra morphism 
$$
\varepsilon:K[(Y_{ij})]\to K[(x_{ij})],\quad Y_{ij}\mapsto x_{ij}.
$$

> Is $I$ finitely generated? If it is, can one give an explicit finite set of generators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87429/generators-of-a-certain-ideal/87464#87464).